# Which concept i want use to get following output using SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server

My Table having following data's

```
 ID  | Name
 --- | ---------
 1   | Apple
 2   | Microsoft
 3   | Samsung       and so on...
```

In my case, input is '`1,2,3`'.

And i need output is '`Apple,Microsoft,Samsung`'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STUFF((
       SELECT ','+ Name 
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE ID in (1, 2, 3)
       FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS Names
```

Result:

> Apple,Microsoft,Samsung

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `XML PATH`

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            T.Name + ', '
        FROM 
            Tbl T
        WHERE
            Id in (1, 2, 3)
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) DesiredOutput
```

Result looks like `Apple, Microsoft, Samsung,`

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [Database Name]

SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

As SQL server doesn't support input in runtime, you can either create a stored procedure and pass the input value while executing it. or just run the following query.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID)
```